# Start Time and End Time removed from Scheduler in JMeter 5.0

Tags: jmeter, scheduler, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-5.0

I've been using JMeter 3.1 forever, but recently I've upgraded to 5.0.

Did they remove the Start Time and End Time from the scheduler in the Thread Groups? If so, is there another way to set them via the GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was [removed in JMeter 4.0](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html)

> **Incompatible changes**
>   Start time and End date of Thread Group have been removed, see [Bug 61549](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61549)

You should move to execute scheduling on other software, for example using Jenkins which can integrate JMeter using [Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=42468533#content/view/42468533)

> includes the feature of setting the final build status as good, unstable or failed, based on the reported error percentage.
>   Report formats supported:
>
> JMeter XML and CSV format, also Summarizer log output
>   Taurus Tool Final Stats XML (through it, you can publish summaries from JMeter, Gatling, Grinder, Siege, ab, Selenium and many others)