# Where I can find scheduler start time and end timie functionalities for JMeter 5.1.1?

Tags: jmeter, scheduled-tasks, jmeter-5.0

From the recent versions of JMeter release, I couldn't see Start and End Time options in JMeter's Scheduler Configuration tab from Thread Group screen.

[image]

How we can schedule date and time from the JMeter's latest version 5.1.1? Else we need to execute that scenario from **Duration** and **Startup Delay** option itself?

Can any one please suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start Time and End Time removed from Scheduler in JMeter 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823537/start-time-and-end-time-removed-from-scheduler-in-jmeter-5-0)

Answer (score 0):

This has been remove in version 4.0. Better ways to schedule a test are for example:

- Jenkins + JMeter maven plugin
- Jenkins + Performance plugin
- Windows Scheduler or Cron