# Schedule Test in Jmeter

Tags: api, automation, jmeter, scheduled-tasks

I'm having trouble scheduling tests on Jmeter.

How do I do this kind of scheduling?

I would like to run tests every 1 hour to validate latency ....

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `cron` on linux?  Scheduled Tasks on Windows?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823537/start-time-and-end-time-removed-from-scheduler-in-jmeter-5-0/53826280?r=SearchResults#53826280

Comment: Guys, very thanks!!!!!! you helped me a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options are in:

1. Configure [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to run `Forever` and add a [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler to sleep for 3600000 milliseconds between iterations
2. Use operating system task scheduling features like:

   - Windows [task sheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/what-s-new-in-task-scheduler)
   - Linux [crontab](https://linuxconfig.org/linux-crontab-reference-guide)
   - MacOS [launchd](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-use-launchd-to-run-services-in-macos-b972ed1e352)
3. Use a 3rd-party [Continous Integration](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jenkins-vs-other-open-source-continuous-integration-servers/) server to orchestrate JMeter job, all of them allow scheduling job executions in a variety of ways